# Python: read the date indices of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df2.index[0:10]
Out[35]: 
Index([2000-01-03 00:00:00, 2000-01-04 00:00:00, 2000-01-05 00:00:00,
       2000-01-06 00:00:00, 2000-01-07 00:00:00, 2000-01-10 00:00:00,
       2000-01-11 00:00:00, 2000-01-12 00:00:00, 2000-01-13 00:00:00,
       2000-01-14 00:00:00],
      dtype='object')
```

How can I convert the original index to make the following command work?

```
M = df2.index.get_loc('2000-01-03')   # Not work now
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.to_datetime` function to convert the given index to `datetime`. You can find out more about `pandas.to_datetime` at [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Try this:

```
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
print(df2.index.get_loc("2000-01-03"))
```

**Output:**

```
0
```